# Making a regular list from Irregular CSV data--Missing Columns

Tags: python, list, sorting

Backstory:
I received a 300+ page word doc of information in a single column. Using VBA and excel, I transposed the data using a delimiter (last names are the only all caps at the beginning of a string).

So now I have row data. Ideally, I need the columns to be:

name v1 v2 v3 v1 v2 v3 v1 v2 v3 v1 v2 v3

and so on for all triplets.

Where the problem comes up is that v1 is not always in all instances. if v1 in the first cycle is the same as v1 in the second cycle, then original data just skipped reentering v1.

Example:

`John v1 v2 v3 v1 v2 v3 v1 v2 v3` (Ideal!)

`Jimm v1 v2 v3 v2 v3 v2 v3 v1 v2 v3` (NOT ideal!)

In the end, I'd like Jimm to match John column for column with either blanks in the court columns or an if(offense, check if court satisfied, if so proceed, if not use previous court.

Luckily, my v1, v2, and v3 have consistent delimiters at the beginning of the string (v1= Court: ; v2= Offense ; v3= Sentence). Does anyone have any tips or advice on how to make an iterated list for the data?

SAMPLE DATA:

NAME, First Last

Court: Test Info1

Offense: Test Offense1

Sentence: Test Sentence1

Offense: Test Offense2

Sentence: Test Sentence2

Court: Test Court3

Offense: Test Offense3

Sentence: Test Sentence3

Note: the second cycle does not include court due to it being the same as Court1. This is an issue with how the data was collected.

All I need is either a list where it inserts the redundant courts or a transposed list that has all columns in line.

Comment: Sorry, what are the identifiers for the 3 data types (v1, v2, v3)?

Comment: Do you have a smallish set from which all of the courts are drawn, or a handy way to recognize whether an entry is a court description or not?   For example, are all the courts covered in the first column, the one you're sure of?  If so, that would make things simple.

Comment: Why don't you use an array and while filling look back by index 1 if v1 is empty to copy the data over from the last entry?

Comment: Thank you for the questions/feedback. I've updated the post to include some sample data. I've got a few thousands of rows with data like this (NAME is a delimiter for new row entries and Court: Offense: and Sentence: are delimiters for columns).

Comment: Oh, then you're in even better shape than I thought -- I thought you hadn't matched the values to which column they were.  Then you can simply loop over each line, recording the last "Court:" line you saw as you go. If the line starts with "Offense:" and the last line you printed wasn't a Court, then print the Court.  Alternatively, you can always print the last Court line you saw whenever you see an Offense line, and then remove neighbouring duplicates at the end.

Comment: Yeah...that would be the easiest.
If offense(check if previous=court, true:print offense, false:print previous court) and loop down the list. Mind helping me type that in python? I've got rudimentary VBA and some front end, but having hell of a time doing hard programming.

Comment: It seems like it would be better to have one row per offense. Then the columns could be (name, court, offense, sentence). Do you know if your names will be unique. If the name strings match is it always the same person? If so, then that could be the key to a dict of three. Anyway from there you could export as csv if you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

There are slicker ways to do this, but I've tried to write this in the Python closest to the algorithm that you understood:

```
with open("crimes.txt") as fp_in, open("fixedcrimes.txt", "w") as fp_out:
    previous_court = None
    previous_line = None
    for line in fp_in:
        if line.startswith("Offense:"):
            if not previous_line.startswith("Court:"):
                fp_out.write(previous_court)
        if line.startswith("Court:"):
            previous_court = line
        fp_out.write(line)
        previous_line = line
```

The first line makes two file objects.  You can loop over the lines of a text file using `for line in:`, and I think everything else should make sense.  (Don't forget that indentation matters in Python.)  Also note that your files don't seem to be standard csv: some lines seem to use a colon-space as the delimiter, but the NAME line seems to use a comma-space.

Anyway, the above code should turn

```
NAME, First Last
Court: Test Info1
Offense: Test Offense1
Sentence: Test Sentence1
Offense: Test Offense2
Sentence: Test Sentence2
Court: Test Court3
Offense: Test Offense3
Sentence: Test Sentence3
```

into

```
NAME, First Last
Court: Test Info1
Offense: Test Offense1
Sentence: Test Sentence1
Court: Test Info1
Offense: Test Offense2
Sentence: Test Sentence2
Court: Test Court3
Offense: Test Offense3
Sentence: Test Sentence3
```

Comment: So I tried running the script and playing with it to fix it, but it is just rewriting the file without adding in the blank rows. The error is  happening with the 'if line.startswith("Offense:"):' -- I've tested based on 

true= ' fp_out.write("TESTING") ' and the end result is still just my raw data. 


After reading more about str.startswith() I'm at a loss.

Comment: UPDATE:
I changed ' fp_out.write(line) ' (your second last line) to ' fp_out.write("TESTING") ' and the end result was a single entry on my fixedcrimes.txt that reads "TESTING". 

The script isn't reading down the rows. I tried with .csv (changed file names and such) and the same results occur. Any idea why it isn't iterating down?